# Adding Javascript in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.0. I want to add a Javascript file `show_javascript.js` that is in `/public/javascripts/` to a view `show.html.erb`.

The `show.html.erb` file takes the `<head>...</head>` part from the template `application.html.erb`

I'm wondering how I should add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a generic stylesheet layout you could add the following to `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_link_tag 'show' if params[:action] == 'show' %>
```

You could even use `content_for` params plus `yield` in the `<head>` section like so:

```
layout.html.erb
<head>
  <%= yield(:header) if @content_for_header %>
</head>

product/show.html.erb
<% content_for :header do -%>
  <%= javascript_link_tag 'show_product' %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: I think @Nathan has given the most perfect answer, if it is used only for show.html.erb, then using content_for params plus yield is the way to go. (its just that Nathan has to change his css tag to js tag :D)

Comment: @sameera207 *fixed* thanks, lol, don't know what I was thinking :P

Comment: Isn't it ```javascript_include_tag```? http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag